# Operator "! " not working with "&&" operator

Tags: php, codeigniter

Following is my code:

```
<?php
$acl_test = "companies";
$act_test2 = "contractor";

if (!($this->acl->hasPermission($acl_test)) && ($this->acl->hasPermission($acl_test2))) {
    ?>

    <li <?php print ($selected == 'companies' || $selected == 'contractor') ? 'class="selected"' : ''; ?>>
        <a class="top-level" href="#">Clients</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="<?php print site_url('companies'); ?>">Company</a></li>
            <li><a href="<?php print site_url('contractors'); ?>">Contractor</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
<?php } ?>
```

Now, want I would like to do is basically, I am validating that logged in user has the permission to view the following link. This works fine if i put the check individually on each link. Although i any user has the one of the permission that he would be able to see the `Clients` link. Now, if any user does not have any permission to view link then he should not able to see the `Clients` link either. But something wrong with logical operation.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Your logical expression literally translates to `!a && a`. This will always evaluate as `false`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Although if any user has the one of the permission that he would be
>   able to see the Clients link. Now, if any user does not have any
>   permission to view link then he should not able to see the Clients
>   link either.

do you mean if any of that permission is true you will let the user see the link?
if that's the case, why don't you try:

```
if($this->acl->hasPermission($acl_test) || $this->acl->hasPermission($acl_test2)){
     // do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`if (!($this->acl->hasPermission($acl_test)) && ($this->acl->hasPermission($acl_test)))` is equal to `if (0 && 1)` which will always be equal to 0.

You're probably not using the correct function / code after `&&`